# Apache: show files in a directory

Tags: permissions, apache-2.2

I have a private directory with some files, I'm able to do an HTTP authentication but when I try to show the files in the directory I get a Forbidden Error. How i can edit my .htaccess file in a way to show the directory content?

This is my .htaccess now:

```
AuthUserFile /private/.htpasswd
AuthName "Private"
AuthType Basic 
require user member
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn on directory listings. Add this:

```
Options +Indexes
```